# Regex Case Insensitive with input match

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to make validation for an html input by assigning via javascript a regex using the following code:

```
$("#"+field.field_id).attr("data-validation",'custom');
$("#"+field.field_id).attr("data-validation-regexp",field.regex);
```

If I set the regex to

```
^(Server (\d{1,2}))$
```

Then it works only with input 'Server ..'
But i want the input Server to work with case insensitive. Like 'SERVER' or 'sErver'......
I tried to put ^(Server (\d{1,2}))$/i but it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
^([Ss][Ee][Rr][Vv][Ee][Rr] (\d{1,2}))$
```

to make it case insensitive.

There is no support of `i` (ignore case flag) in input pattern since it is compiled with the global, ignoreCase, and multiline flags disabled.

Comment: In this case, you can just set `i` flag, since `\d` is not affected by casing (as far as ASCII goes).

Comment: Problem is in HTML5 input regex there is no way to add `i` flag.

Comment: Oh, you are correct. And reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-pattern

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work, because you're not using open slash for regex:

```
^(Server (\d{1,2}))$/i
```

But this should work:

```
/^(Server (\d{1,2}))$/i
```