# How can i match a word in regex, case insensitive, where a regex is in double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

```
 var regexFromDb  = "^.*(MOUSE).*$";
 var regularExp = new RegExp(regexStringFromDabase)

 var stringToMatch = "i like to eat a moUse";

 var matches = regularExp.exec(stringToMatch ); 
 var result =  (matches != null && stringToMatch == matches[0]);
 console.log(result);
```

I need to have the regex match any combination of `upper/lowercase` of the word `'mouse'`.

However the regex string comes from the database, and it is inserted there as double quotes. So you cannot modify the javascript code, only the `regexFromDb` variable, it's content, and you also cannot have `/regexpression/`, only what is the content between doublequotes, excluding the doublequotes

Comment: I cannot modify the javascript code, only the 'regexStringFromDatabase'

Comment: `"^.*([Mm][Oo][Uu][Ss][Ee]).*$"`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858038/regex-case-insensitive-with-input-match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to test an input string to match a regular expression, `RegExp.test` is most appropriate, return a boolean. `RegExp.exec` gives you an array-like return value with all capture groups and matched indexes..

As Nick pointed out, you can use `"^.*([Mm][Oo][Uu][Ss][Ee]).*$"`

```js
const stringToMatch1 = "i like to eat a MoUsE";
const stringToMatch2 = "i like to eat";

const regexFromDb = "^.*([Mm][Oo][Uu][Ss][Ee]).*$";
const regularExp = new RegExp(regexFromDb)

const matches1 = regularExp.test(stringToMatch1);
const matches2 = regularExp.test(stringToMatch2);

console.log(matches1);
console.log(matches2);
```